# Is it correct html syntax?

Tags: html, semantics

I'm creating a team members section for the website.

```html
<div class="team-member">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/john-doe.jpg" alt="John Doe">
    <figcaption>
      <h4>John Doe</h4>
      <p>Photographer</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Is it correct to put this code inside figcaption?

Comment: There is a useful reference for such things: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption

Comment: Run your code through an HTML validator. That would answer your question without needing anyone else's help.

Comment: I putted it inside validator, does it enough?

Answer (score 0):

Please check W3C reference. I believe you want to display the team section with the bio and photo for every person.

It doesn't look like the figure tag fits good for your needs.

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that **can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning**.

I'd prefer to use divs within the section tag.